# Show that $ \ g_2: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $g_2: x \to x^{-1}$ (inverse map) is not continuous.

Tags: topological-groups, product-space

Let $(\Bbb R,+)$ be given the semi-open topology, i.e., the topological basis consists of open sets like
$\{ [a,b)\}$.

Then show that,

$(i) \ g_1: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$  given by $(x,y) \to xy$ is continuous,

$(ii) \ g_2: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $g_2: x \to x^{-1}$ is not continuous.

**My appraoch:**

$(i)$ At first,

$g_1: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and then $g_1: [a,b) \times [c,d) \to [u, v)$. But how does $g_1^{-1}([u,v))$ contains into the domain?

Also help me to show the $(ii)$.

As $0 \in [0,b)$  but what is $g_2^{-1}([0,b))$ ?

Comment: In order for (ii) to make sense, you also need to define $g_2(0)$.

Comment: @ElliotG, for $(ii)$ it just inverse map as in topological group

Comment: @ElliotG In context, I think this refers to the additive inverse (and the group action in (i) is addition, not multiplication).

Comment: @RobertShore, yes, it is inverse map in additive group $(\Bbb R,+)$

Comment: I see. Leaving comment in case others are confused.

Comment: For (ii), this boils down to showing that a half-open interval of the form $(a, b] = g_2^{-1}([-b, -a))$ is not open in this topology.

Comment: @RobertShore, ok and for $(i)$ ? How to show $(i)$ is continuous?

Comment: That's a little harder.  Using additive notation, $g_1^{-1}([a, b))= \{ (x, y) \mid a \leq x+y \lt b \}$ so you need to show that set is open in the induced product topology.

Comment: @RobertShore, that is I have to show that $g_1^{-1}([a,b))=[a_1,b_1) \times [a_1',b_1')$ for some $a_1,b_1$

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Draw the graph.  You'll see that's not true.  You need to show that it's a union of such sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the following definition of continuity: $f : X \to Y$ is continuous at $x \in X$ if for any basis set $V \subset Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an open set $U \subset X$ containing $x$ such that $f(U) \subset Y$. We say that $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at each $x$ in $X$.

Fix $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and an open set $[c,d) \subset \mathbb{R}$ containing $g_1((a,b)) = a + b$. Then $c \leq a + b < d$. In particular, this means that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $a + b + \epsilon < d$.

If
$$
(x,y) \in \left[a , a + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \times \left[b , b + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)
$$
Then
$$
g_1((x,y)) = x + y \in [a + b, a + b + \epsilon) \subset [c, d)
$$
Thus
$$
g_1\left(\left[a , a + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \times \left[b , b + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \right) \subset [c,d)
$$
This shows that $g_1$ is continuous at $(a,b)$. Since $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary, this shows that $g_1$ is continuous.

Can you see what goes wrong for $g_2$?

Comment: Thank you. Yes in $g_2$, probably not continuous at $0$. For,  if we take any nbd of $0$, say $[0,b)$ but $g_2^{-1}([0,b))$ contains no nbd of $0$ in the domain. Is it ?

Comment: Something like that. The reason $g_2$ fails to be continuous is basically that preimages of open sets $[a,b)$ look like $(-b, a]$, which are not open. We don't have this "reversal" problem when dealing with addition.